# Problemas com a Inserção no Firebase

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, nosql

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação nativa em Android que utiliza mapas, a inserção está acontecendo normalmente através do código abaixo.

Local é uma variável do tipo `LatLng`.

```
mDataBase.child("location").child("Roubo").child(String.valueOf( new Date().getTime())).setValue(local);
```

Fica dessa forma no Firebase:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas gostaria de que após a inserção fica-se dessa forma, ao invés de somente ter latitude e longitude, também tive-se um `double` chamado score e que depois eu consegui-se ler esse dado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se é isso que estas procurando:

```
Double score = 0.0
String today = String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());

mDataBase.child("location").child("Roubo").child(today).setValue(local);
mDataBase.child("location").child("Roubo").child(today).child("score").setValue(score);
```